# Единственное или множественное?

Tags: стилистика

Помнится, так и не нашел (уже после экзамена) в доступной тогда литературе однозначного ответа на один из контрольных вопросов по стилистике.
"Гость вместе с хозяином поднялся/поднялись на крыльцо."
Экзаменатор согласился, что, если бы было "гостья" - то, конечно, "поднялась", а если б, напротив, "гость вместе с хозяйкой" - то "поднялись";  в варианте же "гость вместе с хозяином" допустимо и единственное, и множественное число глагола.
Собственно, такой ответ я тогда выдумал на ходу, без малейших оснований.
Может, кто прояснит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При оборотах, образованных сочетанием **«именительный падеж плюс творительный падеж с предлогом с»** сказуемое может стоять как в форме **множественного**, так и в форме **единственного** числа.

- **Форма множественного** числа сказуемого показывает, что в роли подлежащего выступает все сочетание, т.е. действие приписывается двум взаимосвязанным равноправным субъектам.
- **Форма единственного** числа сказуемого показывает, что подлежащим является только существительное в именительном падеже, а существительное в творительном падеже выступает в роли дополнения, обозначая лицо, сопутствующее производителю действия.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Это, как я только что выяснил, из Розенталя цитата, а то уж я подумал, что Вы сами так чеканно формулируете.

Comment: В справочнике по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию, соавтором которого является вышеупомянутый лингвист, изложены многие классические «спорные ситуации», которые подвергают разбору в процессе изучения аналогичных дисциплин в вузах. На его страницах также есть более детальный анализ синтаксических норм в рамках заданной тематики.

Первоисточник должен быть известен, в этом Вы, разумеется, правы.

Answer (score 0):

Число сказуемого зависит и от того, чем выражено подлежащее.
См. "Пособие для занятий по русскому языку в старших классах средней школы" 
В. Ф. Грекова,С. Е Крючкова, Л. А. Чешко (стр.173)